# How to list all items of an object in ionic 3?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Personal maybe my question is not being too clear, but what I am trying to do is that by clicking on the Feed item in the categories screen, be listed all companies that are related to Feeding on the companies screen.

I'm very confused because as there will be several companies in each category I have no idea how to list them correctly, could someone help me?

The first image we have my category screen and clicking on the Feed item is to be shown all companies that are related to feed category.

[image: Page Category]

My next image is related to the Company page and it is here that will list all companies that are related to Food

[image: Page Company]

My items are being stored as an Object within my App.

Here is my `home.html`

```
    <ion-content id="#pageTop">
  <ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)" placeholder="Pesquisar"></ion-searchbar>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
    <ion-thumbnail item-left>
        <img [src]="item.imagem">
    </ion-thumbnail>
    <h2>{{ item?.category }}</h2>
    <button ion-button clear item-end color="primary" (click)="itemTapped($event, item)">Abrir</button>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-fab right bottom>
    <button ion-fab color="secondary" (click)="pageScroller()"><ion-icon name="ios-arrow-up"></ion-icon></button>
  </ion-fab>
```

And inside my `home.ts` is where objects are stored

```
    initializeItems(){
    this.items = [
      { category: 'Alimentação', imagem: '../../assets/imgs/alimentacao.jpeg'},
    ]
  }
```

And it is in this part that I am having doubts, because my intention is to add in the Object an array of type company and to add all the companies there, however it is not possible to place duplicate object.

Like this example

```
 this.items = [
      { category: 'Alimentação', imagem: '../../assets/imgs/alimentacao.jpeg', company:'companyOne', company:'companyTwo'},
    ]
```

And my `company.html` it is like this

```
    <ion-item *ngFor="let company of company">
      <h2>{{ company?.category }}</h2>
    </ion-item>
```

And my `company.ts` it is like this

```
   company: any[];
   constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.company = this.navParams.get('item');
  }
```

Comment: Indtead of adding each company inside items array add one property called “companies” and assign array to it. The use ngFor in your template for that property. Makes sense?

Comment: Do you have any docs so I can read and understand more or some examples?

Answer (score 2):

You're saying your intentions was to add an array of company objects (as far as I understand). I'm not sure why you finally didn't.

I think you should store companies as an array in your item :

```
    this.items = [
        {   category: 'Alimentação', 
            imagem: '../../assets/imgs/alimentacao.jpeg', 
            companies:[{ /*first company object*/}, {/*second company object*/}]
        }];
```

And you would display the companies associated with an item like this :

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let company of item.companies">
        <h2>{{ company?.category }}</h2>
    </ion-item>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: The objects inside companies are commented out, I tried to reproduce here and gave an error in the syntax

Comment: I don't know the real content of your company object, so I put comments as placeholders. I guess it would look like this : `companies:[{ name:"myFirstComp", category:"foo"}, { name:"mySecondComp", category:"bar" }]`

Comment: I will test as soon as possible, as there will be several categories and each category will have a company. And by clicking on the category in the home screen, I want to appear in the companies page only the items that are linked in the selected category.